# building ghc 7.2.1 on opensuse

Tags: haskell, ghc, opensuse, building

Just wondering if anyone here has had success building GHC 7.2.1 on OpenSuSE. I'm running into errors, with 7.0.3 currently installed.

```
chmod +x inplace/lib/ghc-split
"rm" -f                              inplace/bin/ghc-stage1
echo '#!/bin/sh'                             >> inplace/bin/ghc-stage1
echo 'executablename="/home/gatoatigrado/Downloads/ghc-7.2.1/inplace/lib/ghc-stage1"'            >> inplace/bin/ghc-stage1
echo 'datadir="/home/gatoatigrado/Downloads/ghc-7.2.1/inplace/lib"'       >> inplace/bin/ghc-stage1
echo 'bindir="/home/gatoatigrado/Downloads/ghc-7.2.1/inplace/bin"'        >> inplace/bin/ghc-stage1
echo 'topdir="/home/gatoatigrado/Downloads/ghc-7.2.1/inplace/lib"'     >> inplace/bin/ghc-stage1
echo 'pgmgcc="/usr/bin/gcc"'            >> inplace/bin/ghc-stage1
cat ghc/ghc.wrapper               >> inplace/bin/ghc-stage1
chmod +x                               inplace/bin/ghc-stage1
/usr/bin/gcc -E  -undef -traditional -P -DTOP='"/home/gatoatigrado/Downloads/ghc-7.2.1"'  -x c -Iincludes libffi/package.conf.in -o libffi/package.conf.inplace.raw
grep -v '^#pragma GCC' libffi/package.conf.inplace.raw | sed -e 's/""//g' -e 's/:[   ]*,/: /g' > libffi/package.conf.inplace
"inplace/bin/ghc-pkg" update --force libffi/package.conf.inplace
Reading package info from "libffi/package.conf.inplace" ... done.
ghc-pkg: too few bytes. Failed reading at byte position 44111
make[1]: *** [libffi/package.conf.inplace] Error 1
make[1]: *** Deleting file `libffi/package.conf.inplace'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Thanks in advance.

bug report: http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/5446

Comment: Also, if anyone knows how to use OpenSuSE's build service so that GHC could be installed as a regular package, that would be super. Unfortunately 6.12 is the latest packaged version for OpenSuSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Peter Trommler has succeeded - here are [rpms for ghc-7.2.1](https://build.opensuse.org/package/binaries?package=ghc&project=home%3Aptrommler%3Adevel%3Alanguages%3Ahaskell&repository=openSUSE_11.4) from his [home:ptrommler:devel:languages:haskell repository on the OBS](https://build.opensuse.org/project/show?project=home%3Aptrommler%3Adevel%3Alanguages%3Ahaskell).  (Even though the latest build appears to have failed, there are packages from a previous build.)

I've mailed Peter and the maintainer of the [official devel:languages:haskell repositories](https://build.opensuse.org/project/show?project=devel%3Alanguages%3Ahaskell) to ask if there's any way the official ones could be updated.